# All UWP solution/project deployment failed. DEP0600: Deployment failed. UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal, visual-studio-2017

I'am trying to deploy an UWP application to my local machine, but Visual Studio told me an Error!

```
DEP0600: Deployment failed. UnauthorizedAccessException - Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.People_10.1.3160.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppXManifest.xml' is denied. [0x80070005]
```

Then I'am trying to create a new Blank App, and deploy it. But they failed too.

And run Visual Studio as Administrator, it's failed, nothing has changed.

**What's wrong with my Windows 10, how can I fix it?**

It's my system infomation and Visual Studio version:

**Developer Mode is On**

Windows 10:

```
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Home Insider Preview
OS Version:                10.0.15031 N/A Build 15031
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Standalone Workstation
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
```

Visual Studio 2017 RC:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 RC
Version 15.0.26206.0 D15REL
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.7.02036
Installed Version: Community

Visual Basic 2017 RC
Microsoft Visual Basic 2017 RC

Visual C# 2017 RC
Microsoft Visual C# 2017 RC

Visual C++ 2017 RC
Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 RC

Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package   8.6.00201.7
Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2017   15.0.30206.0
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2017

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2017   5.2.50127.0
For additional information, visit https://www.asp.net/

Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   15.0.30126.0
Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0

Common Azure Tools   1.9
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

JavaScript Language Service   2.0
JavaScript Language Service

JavaScript Project System   2.0
JavaScript Project System

JavaScript UWP Project System   2.0
JavaScript UWP Project System

KofePackagePackage Extension   1.0
KofePackagePackage Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

Microsoft MI-Based Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting Visual Studio to MI compatible debuggers

Microsoft Visual Studio VC Package   1.0
Microsoft Visual Studio VC Package

Node.js Tools   1.3.41102.00
Adds support for developing and debugging Node.js apps in Visual Studio

NuGet Package Manager   4.0.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit http://docs.nuget.org/.

Sandcastle Help File Builder   SHFB
Visual Studio integration for the Sandcastle Help File Builder.
https://GitHub.com/EWSoftware/SHFB

SQL Server Data Tools   15.1.61701.270
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

TypeScript   2.1.5.0
TypeScript tools for Visual Studio

Visual Studio Spell Check Everywhere   VSSpellCheckEverywhere
An extension that enables spell checking within any Visual Studio file editor or tool window that uses WPF text boxes.
https://GitHub.com/EWSoftware/VSSpellChecker

Visual Studio Spell Checker   VSSpellChecker
An editor extension that checks the spelling of comments, strings, and plain text as you type or interactively with tool windows.
https://GitHub.com/EWSoftware/VSSpellChecker

Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows Apps   15.0.26206.00
The Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows apps allow you to build a single universal app experience that can reach every device running Windows 10: phone, tablet, PC, and more. It includes the Microsoft Windows 10 Software Development Kit.
```

=======================

Well interesting.

**Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 have this issue too.**

It's a Windows 10 bug?

[image: Visual Studio 2015 Update 3]

[image: Visual Studio 2017 RC]

====================================

I'm reinstalled my Windows 10 Insider Preview 15031 and Visual Studio 2017 RC.

Now this issue has been fixed, it's not cool hah.

[image: Fixed]

Comment: Did you try to start VS as administrator?

Comment: @Blackstar Yes, I try! It's failed.

Comment: Really strange, has the app any capability about contacts?

Comment: @JuanPabloGarciaCoello No, the Blank App's Package.appxmanifest only calls one capability "internetClient". I don't know why a Blank App can't deploy using VS 2017, now I'm installing VS 2015.

Comment: @Garfield550 reinstalling both Windows and VS fixed the issue? I'm sorry to hear about all the trouble. If you are still hitting this issue let me know - I'll try my best to help.

Comment: @DanielJacobson Thank you!